# How to restrict certain email addresses in RS Forms Pro Joomla

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, joomla

I use an RSFormPro for a contact form in my Joomla v3.1.x site.

For a particular reason, I need to add 3 or 4 email addresses that are 'not allowed' to submit the form upon validation.

i.e.
joe@domain1.com,
frank@gmail.com,
sue@yahoo.com,
deniise@domain2.com

How can i do this ? Please advice.

=============== Edited

For anyone else looking for an answer, please see below:

Answer...

For the script to work properly you will have to replace the below "mytextbox" with your email textbox exact name.

The script is added within the "Script called on form process" area
(Joomla backend > Components > RSForm!Pro > Manage Forms > your form > Properties > PHP Scripts).

```
$array = array('joe@domain1.com','frank@gmail.com','sue@yahoo.com','denise@domain2.com');

foreach($array as $arr){
if($_POST['form']['mytextbox'] == $arr)
$invalid[] = RSFormProHelper::getComponentId('mytextbox');
}
```

So all of the email addresses that you see in the above array, will validate & will prompt an 'invalid' message.

Comment: You're going to need to supply a lot more information about the RSFormPro code and how it interacts with Joomla and the database.

Comment: You have paid for an extension and don't want premium support by the developer of the extension? Would be the first place I would go ;)

Comment: Firstly, this question would suit a Joomla developer. Secondly, yes... I have submitted a ticket to the extension developer for support - but thought I would also try here, as I need the answer fairly urgently. No worries if I am barking up the tree of the wrong site to get some advice ;-)